# When to use virtual methods/downcasting vs when to avoid it (C++)

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

I have class "Item" and some derived classes from that

```
class Item
{
 public:
 string name;
 string type;
 int value;
 int requiredLvl
 bool isEquipped;
};

class Weapon : public Item
{
 public:
 int minDmg;
 int maxDmg;
};

class Armor : public Item
{
 public:
 int defense;
};
```

And then I ran into an issue because I would store all of these objects in one vector of Item pointers, but then at some point I would need to access for example the minDmg and maxDmg values from the derived "Weapon" class, but it's not possible with a base class pointer.

And I've already read that this can be done by creating virtual methods in my classes, or another option is to cast the base class pointer to a derived class pointer.

But my question is, SHOULD I even attempt to do this, or does it make much more sense to change the design of the code, and maybe split the one vector into 3 different vectors, holding Item, Weapons, and Armor pointers?

At first I figured that having one vector to just store the base class pointers would make more sense, also for things like displaying the inventory where I could just loop over one vector instead of 3 different vectors.

And if I wanted to have more derived Item classes, for example maybe "Jewelry", "Consumables" etc.it would mean I'd have to create even more vectors.

So I'm at a crossroad because I know how to solve this issue technically, but I don't know if using virtual methods/casting is even the right approach to something like this, or I should find other ways to do design the program to avoid having to do that.

Comment: You should read GOF, it would answer many questions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns Downcasting "technically" means that   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle was breached. Usually it shuld not be happening in user code,  if it actually needed, it would be a part of visitor or a policy.

Comment: My general advice is to not model structures or object as simple containers of data, but around *behavior* instead. Since C++ supports multiple inheritance it means you can have (for example) a shield that can be equipped (behavior 1), is magical (behavior 2), *and* could be used as a weapon (behavior 3). Yes some basic "item" class could also be used as a simple common ancestor for all items, and that would be basically a simple container of the common item properties. But only inherit from it for the actual concrete items themselves (making a very shallow, one-level, inheritance tree).

Comment: For a container of mixed data you could consider : std::vector<std::variant<Item,Weapon,Armor>>. Another option is to aggregate instead of inherit. Which means you can ask a Weapon for its Item data with a getter and make Item a member of a Weapon. Even if you do OO you should not use inheritance for everything

Comment: Read this first: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/155468/planning-class-inheritance-for-game-objects

Comment: Another interesting pattern you can use is "double dispatch" (variant style) to model interactions between objects (Weapon hits Shield). [Multiple dispatch with variant and multi visitation in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/52495/multiple-dispatch-with-variant-and-multi-visitation-in-c)

Comment: Rule of thumb:  avoid down-casting.   Although there are some specific situations where it is necessary, a need for down-casting when YOU have control of both base and derived class definitions usually indicates a broken design.     Whether you need virtual functions depends on your design but, usually are needed if you have a set of *named behaviours* (represented by virtual functions in the base class) that are overridden and modified by derived classes in order to extend or specialise the named behaviours.